# oracle SQL and ( ) brackets in where

Tags: oracle

I have an application which automatically add brackets after WHERE condition and send it to JDBC Oracle driver, Oracle doesn't like it and thrown: **ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis**

I'm not sure how to work with it in the scope of Oracle syntax, but any suggestion to fix it having this brackets or it's not supported by the syntax?

Original query works just fine:

```
SELECT count(*) as ErrorCount, Engine_name, to_char(log_time,'hh24') as Hour FROM eailog_data.err_log WHERE err_timestamp > sysdate-1/24 GROUP BY engine_name, to_char(log_time,'hh24') HAVING count(*) > 100 AND count(*) > 0 ORDER BY count(*)
```

and 3rd party application modify it like this (note brackets added after **WHERE** condition):

```
SELECT count(*) as ErrorCount, Engine_name, to_char(log_time,'hh24') as Hour 
  FROM eailog_data.err_log 
 WHERE 
       ( 
         err_timestamp > sysdate-1/24 
         GROUP BY engine_name,  
                  to_char(log_time,'hh24') 
          HAVING count(*) > 100 
       ) 
    AND count(*) > 0 
 ORDER BY count(*)
```

Any ideas how to fix SQL with added brackets?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fix the "3rd party application" that mangled the sql in the first place? If someone keeps ramming their car into a wall, the solution is to get rid of that person, not make the wall softer.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. If you have an application that mangles the SQL making it malformed, you should probably get the application fixed (or use something else).

Comment: Your problem lies on this part: ` AND count() > 0` `count()` is an aggregate function and cant be used on WHERE clause it should be on `HAVING count()>0`.

Comment: yeah, in case it's not possible to fix what we have then it's clear to fix the app, but is it not possible? Oracle doesn't support this?

Comment: No. You have an incorrect syntaxe... If you add parentesis to the where clause IT IS where clause, but you are adding the HAVING clause on it which is not possible

Comment: @JorgeCampos basically it's working originally just fine. I deleted HAVING, same issue

Comment: But it still left the group by part... which is another clause inside the where

Comment: @JorgeCampos I deleted it in any case and SQL return the data, but adding ( after WHERE make SQL broken. Can I somehow fix these ( )?

Comment: The only way you fix this is if the `( )` cover just the where clause like: Original : `... WHERE err_timestamp > sysdate-1/24 GROUP BY ...` with the parentesis: `... WHERE ( err_timestamp > sysdate-1/24 ) GROUP BY ...` see that way the syntaxe would not be broken

Comment: @JorgeCampos true, I understand the point. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The `WHERE` clause parenthetical expression needs to end at the end of the `WHERE` clause and the condition in the `HAVING` clause ends with a parenthesis, but never begins.

In terms of adding parenthesis, certainly you could add a parenthesis at the end of the `WHERE` clause and add a parenthesis at the beginning of the `HAVING` clause as follows:

```
SELECT count(*) AS errorcount,
  engine_name,
  to_char(log_time,'hh24') AS HOUR
FROM eailog_data.err_log
WHERE ( err_timestamp > SYSDATE-1/24 )
GROUP BY engine_name,
  to_char(log_time,'hh24')
HAVING ( count(*) > 100 )
AND count(     *) > 0
ORDER BY count(*)
```

Since this is an application, it sounds like you need to work with the author of the application to fix their parenthesis usage.

---

Here is an example using the DUAL table

Before, malformed parenthetical expression in the `WHERE` and `HAVING` clause.

```
SCOTT@dev> SELECT dummy,
  2    COUNT(*)
  3  FROM dual
  4  WHERE (dummy != 'Y'
  5  GROUP BY dummy
  6  HAVING  COUNT( *) = 1)
  7  AND COUNT(     *)  > 0
  8  ORDER BY COUNT(*)
  9  /
WHERE (dummy != 'Y'
             *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

After, corrected parenthetical expression in the 'WHERE' and 'HAVING' clause.

```
    SCOTT@dev> --corrected
    SCOTT@dev> SELECT dummy,
      2    COUNT(*)
      3  FROM dual
      4  WHERE (dummy != 'Y')
      5  GROUP BY dummy
      6  HAVING (COUNT( *) = 1)
      7  AND COUNT(     *)  > 0
      8  ORDER BY COUNT(*)
      9  /

D   COUNT(*)
= ==========
X          1
```

Answer (score 2):

A SQL statement consists of several clauses (some of which are optional):

- the column list
- the table list (`FROM` clause)
- filter conditions (`WHERE` clause)
- aggregate columns (`GROUP BY` clause)
- aggregate conditions (`HAVING` clause)
- etc.

The key concept that seems to be missing is that you can't open a parenthesis in one clause and close it in another. The reason the error you're getting is "missing right parenthesis" is that the SQL engine thinks you're done with the `WHERE` clause as soon as it sees `GROUP BY`. Since there was a un-closed parenthetical at that point, it can't parse any further.

To use an analogy, the SQL you provided is like having the opening and closing parenthesis in different methods in Java. It simply can't work.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways to get around some tool mangling your SQL syntax: Creative SQL to subvert the parser, and convert the SQL.

**Creative SQL**

Parsing Oracle SQL is virtually impossible to do 100% correctly since the syntax is much more complicated than other languages.  This leads to problems with beautifiers and code generators.  I've seen tools fail in ways very similar to your example.

But this complexity also offers many opportunities to subvert tools that try to rewrite SQL.  Try different features until you find something that is immune to their parser.  Here are some ideas:

1. Inline view.  `select * from (select ... from ... where ... ) where 1=1;`
2. Common table expression.  `with some_query as (select ... from ... where ... ) select * from some_query;`
3. Alternative quoting mechanism.

   ```
       select dummy
       from dual
       where '''' = q'<'>' --The parser probably thinks this is still a string.
           and 1 = 1
       group by dummy
       --' --And it probably thinks this is the end.
   ```

**Convert SQL**

In extreme cases there are ways to make Oracle accept completely broken SQL.  Check out
 [SQL Translation Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DRDAA/sql_transl_arch.htm#DRDAA131)
 and [DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_advrwr.htm#ARPLS083).

Those tools are definitely a last resort.  It would be great if we could wave a magic wand and fix all 3rd party programs but we have to live in the real world.